# Elasticsearch error when trying to run bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk

I am setting up Elasticsearch version 7.17.11 on Ubuntu 20.04. It will be a single instance of Elasticsearch but I will have separate instances for Kibana and Logstash. I am trying to recreate our setup in another cloud project without using a cluster for Elasticsearch and those settings are the only differences from a working build as far as I am aware.

This is the error when I run the bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords tool:

```
Failed to authenticate user 'elastic' against https://localhost:9200/_security/_authenticate?pretty
Possible causes include:
 * The password for the 'elastic' user has already been changed on this cluster
 * Your elasticsearch node is running against a different keystore
   This tool used the keystore at /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.keystore


ERROR: Failed to verify bootstrap password
```

The keystore does appear to be at /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.keystore. The password cannot have been already changed because I create a new instance with Terraform every time and run an Ansible playbook against it.

This is my elasticsearch.yml file:

```
node.name: test-elasticsearch
network.host: localhost
http.port: 9200
discovery.type: single-node

# Transport layer
xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode: certificate
xpack.security.transport.ssl.key: /etc/elasticsearch/certs/elasticsearch.key
xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate: /etc/elasticsearch/certs/elasticsearch.crt
xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities: /etc/elasticsearch/certs/ca/ca.crt

# HTTP layer
xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.http.ssl.verification_mode: certificate
xpack.security.http.ssl.key: /etc/elasticsearch/certs/elasticsearch.key
xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate: /etc/elasticsearch/certs/elasticsearch.crt
xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities: /etc/elasticsearch/certs/ca/ca.crt

# Elasticsearch authentication
xpack.security.enabled: true
#xpack.security.enabled: false

path.data: /mnt/elastic_data_disk
path.logs: /mnt/elastic_data_disk
```

The certs have been setup with the bin/elasticsearch-certutil tool and put in the correct paths BTW.

This is the instances.yml file I used to configure the certs BTW (with full public IP - censored here):

```
instances:
- name: "test-elasticsearch"
  ip:
  - "35.xx.xx.xx"
```

Any help is appreciated: I have read all of the related Elastic documentation I am aware of that relates and I am stuck and cannot find anything online. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

I am installing Elasticsearch. I am having trouble with creating the elastic password - it incorrectly says it has already been configured and I cannot proceed without knowing the elastic password.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing something in the Ansible playbook. When you setup the Elasticsearch, Elasticsearch should define the `elastic` user's first password by itself, and send the output to the terminal.

**Recommendation**: Rather than struggling with `elastic` user I recommend you create a new user with `superuser` permissions and check what is happening.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/users-command.html

### To create a superuser:

```
bin/elasticsearch-users useradd username -p password -r superuser
```

Not sure if it works but you can try the same command for elastic user too.